# Creating a new field with asm 4

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

This is the code im using

```
    String fieldName = "lock";
    String fieldType = "Ljava/util/concurrent/locks/Lock;";
    Object initValue = new ReentrantLock();

    cw.visitField(ACC_PUBLIC, fieldName, fieldType, null, initValue).visitEnd();
```

Im attempting to add a line of "Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();"
but asm is throwing a error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value class java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass an object as an initial value.  You need to generate the code which will create the object when the code is run, not when you generated the code.

Comment: How would i do that?, im new to asm

Comment: I suggest you write the code in Java and use the ASMifier to dump the code to regenerate it.  You can also use the http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/ or the IntelliJ plugin to see the code in your IDE.

Comment: You _can_ pass a limited set of object types as an initial value: Integer, Byte, Character, Short, Boolean, Float, Long, Double, String and Type. The last one is part of the ASM library.